# Make Variables Behave Like Global Variables

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, closures, global-variables

I'm wondering if it's possible to move a set of variables from the global scope to a nested scope. Is it possible to use a closure to achieve this in the following context? It must be, right?

The `let` variables probably shouldn't be within the `renderInfo()` scope because `renderInfo()` is called multiple times at load, and this cannot be avoided. Each time `renderInfo()` is called, `render()` renders multiple elements, all of which have a `click` event listener added to them. Hence the variables also can't be here with the way the code is currently structured.

I've tried turning `clickToSort()` into a closure, but I run into issues every time. I can't figure out how to allow all of the elements with the `click` event listener to ***share*** access to the `let` variables.

```
let
  sortNameAscending =
  sortFreeAscending =
  sortSizeAscending = true

// Called multiple times at load.
function renderInfo(a,b,c,d) {

  // Renders multiple elements, and adds an event listener to them, each call.
  function render(){
    // The event listener is added to multiple elements
    // that are also rendered herein.
    ele.addEventListener('click', (e)=>clickToSort(e, cls, 'aString'))
  }

  // This function is added to the click event of tons of elements.
  function clickToSort(e, cls, dataProperty) {

    // How do I move the let variables from the global
    // scope to here, so that they behave as if they
    // are in the global scope? Is it possible with a
    // closure?
    // let
    //  sortNameAscending =
    //  sortFreeAscending =
    //  sortSizeAscending = true

    // I imagine the following code should be wrapped in
    // its own scope, but the scope must have access to
    // the arguments of clickToSort(), and the let variables
    // which should behave as if they are global.
    if (cls.includes('whatever')) {
      sortNameAscending = !sortNameAscending
    } else if (cls.includes('whatever2')) {
      sortFreeAscending = !sortFreeAscending
    } else {
      sortSizeAscending = !sortSizeAscending
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried the following, but it doesn't wanna work.

```
let
  sortNameAscending =
  sortFreeAscending =
  sortSizeAscending = true

function renderInfo(a,b,c,d) {

  function render(){
    // The event listener is added to multiple elements
    // that are also rendered herein.
    ele.addEventListener('click', (e)=>clickToSort(e, cls, 'aString'))
  }

  function clickToSort(e, cls, dataProperty) {

    let
      sortNameAscending =
      sortFreeAscending =
      sortSizeAscending = true

    ;(function whatevs(){
      if (cls.includes('whatever')) {
        sortNameAscending = !sortNameAscending
      } else if (cls.includes('whatever2')) {
        sortFreeAscending = !sortFreeAscending
      } else {
        sortSizeAscending = !sortSizeAscending
      }
    )()
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why, although it probably has something to do with the fact that I've bound the `clickToSort()` function to the elements, instead of perhaps returning a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the whole function into an [immediately invoked function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). That would ensure closure on your three variables while letting your calls share the same data.

In your anonymous function, you can declare your enclosed variables and return the function which was initially called `renderInfo`. When your code is executed, those three variables will be declared and kept inside the anonymous function's scope, then `renderInfo` will be given the value of a function.

```js
// Called multiple times at load.
const renderInfo = (function() {

  let
    sortNameAscending =
    sortFreeAscending =
    sortSizeAscending = true

  return function(a, b, c, d) {

    // Renders multiple elements, and adds an event listener to them, each call.
    function render() {
      // The event listener is added to multiple elements
      // that are also rendered herein.
      ele.addEventListener('click', (e) => clickToSort(e, cls, 'aString'))
    }

    // This function is added to the click event of tons of elements.
    function clickToSort(e, cls, dataProperty) {

      if (cls.includes('whatever')) {
        sortNameAscending = !sortNameAscending
      } else if (cls.includes('whatever2')) {
        sortFreeAscending = !sortFreeAscending
      } else {
        sortSizeAscending = !sortSizeAscending
      }
    }

  }

})()
```

---

A simple example of using an IIFE (*Immediately Invoked Function Expression*) to create a closure is the following:

```js
const add = (function() {
  let sum = 0;
  return function() {
    return ++sum;
  }
})()

console.log(add())
console.log(add())
console.log(add())
console.log(add())
```

Comment: isnt this going to run into issues? like every time `renderInfo()` is called at load, the `let` variables will be reset to `true` if they have already been changed since then, right? or am i wrong and a giant n00b at closures? is it not possible to turn `clickToSort` into a closure?

Comment: @oldboy What is inside the closure (i.e. inside the anonymous function before the function return) is only executed once. Calling `renderInfo` *n* times will not reset those three variables.

Comment: oh wow really?? so counter intuitive. where can i read more about this?

Comment: also, is it not possible to turn `clickToSort` into a closure?

Comment: When you come to think about it, it's not counter-intuitive really... but can surprise! I've added another example in my answer.

Comment: so basically the nested function inherits the IIFE from the outer function right?

Comment: Everything inside your IIFE *has* access to its scope.

Comment: @oldboy, what are you looking for by using a closure on `clickToSort`?

Comment: honestly, i could just put the variables in the global scope, but id like to move the `let` variables inside of `clickToSort` if possible. i wont lose anything by doing that. i just wanted to know if it was possible, and learn how if it was

Comment: Ok, it's clear you're looking to share properties between different instances. Therefore, you simply can't declare them inside something that is specific to an instance. You're forced to place those in the outer scope - a scope that contains all those instances -. That can either be the global scope or preferably a closure which allows you to keep them safe.

Comment: yeah i realized i misspoke there. in my actual code i tried placing the variables inside the `renderInfo` scope, but obviously it caused each set of elements to have their own set of variables. any idea why in this [codepen], the `t` argument is logging as `undefined`?

Comment: whoops myb [heres the link](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/VwYxVmy?editors=1111)

Comment: @oldboy You are not passing any arguments to your IIFE. That's why `t` is undefined. You can pass arguments like this: `(function(e,t) { console.log(e,t) })('yes', 'blue')`

Comment: huh? but the value is being passed to IIFE via `(e)=>clickToSort(e, 'theValueIsHere?')`?

Comment: @oldboy, in your snippet, `clickToSort` has no arguments, the IIFE wrapping up `clickToSort`, on the other hand, has two!

Comment: so the parameters of anonymous functions (i.e. `const whatever = function(e, t)` are simply ignored? is `const whatever(e, t) = (function() ... )()` valid JS?

Comment: @oldboy, no, nothing is ignored, you can pass arguments to your IIFE: `const f = (function(a,b) { return function() { return a+b } })(1,2)` or to your wrapped function: `const g = function() { return function(a,b) { return a+b } })()`. We are setting `f` and `g` to the result of a particular IIFE. As a result, both `f` and `g` are functions: `f` has 0 arguments and is called with `f()` (returns `3`) and `g` has two arguments and is called with e.g. `f(10, 101)` (returns `111`). `f` and `g` are variables which values' are functions with parameters. Also `const whatever(e, t) =...` is not valid.

Comment: i realized what was wrong. for the nested function to access the arguments of the outer function, the nested function must mirror the parameters of the outer function

Comment: Usually, you won't be needing parameters in your IIFE.

Comment: i was just wondering why i wasnt able to access the parameters passed to the outer function. anyways thanks for ur help